# Python Requests module - Strip back content

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to call a web request from the link specified below (may have changed slightly depending when you read this) but I only want a specific part of it, it's all one line. From the part `"version":"12.30"`I want to keep the **12.30** What code would I need to use?

> LINK:
>   *https://fortnite-public-service-stage.ol.epicgames.com/fortnite/api/version*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the requests module that it should convert the json string to a dictionary and then access the version

```py
url = "https://fortnite-public-service-stage.ol.epicgames.com/fortnite/api/version"
response = requests.get(url)
version = response.json()["version"]
```